# Can Relic of Progenitus be used to prevent a card being fetched from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

I played a [Relic of Progenitus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRelic%20of%20Progenitus%5d) on my first turn. My opponent (who went first) activates a [fetch land](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=405115), then casts [Wrenn and Six](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWrenn%20and%20Six%5d). Can I force the opponent to exile a card from their graveyard in response to stop them from returning the fetch land to their hand?

Comment: 1) Probably obvious, but did your opponent use W6's +1 ability? Just casting W6 doesn't fetch a card from the graveyard. 2) Are there any other cards in your opponent's graveyard? (Again, please edit your question to add this information rather than adding another comment and/or answer)

Answer (score 2):

Planeswalker abilities are activated abilities; they go on the stack and can be responded to with instants, or other abilities which can be activated 'at instant speed', like either of Relic of Progenitus' ones. So that would work to stop them from using the fetch land twice.

Note that returning the land to the hand is part of the resolution of the effect, not the cost. This is different from the situation where they would activate the fetch land and sacrifice it as part of the cost; then, instant-speed land destruction would *not* work.

Comment: Caveat: Relic of Progenitus, unless activated for the {1} ability, only forces opponent to exile one card from their graveyard. If they have another card in the graveyard other than the fetchland (or if they have an instant they can play, e.g. Lightning Bolt) then they can exile that card instead and still leave the fetchland in the graveyard.

Comment: "then, instant-speed land destruction would not work." In this particular case, it would: the OP worded their question as being in response to the casting of Wrenn and Six, rather than using its loyalty ability.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you want, use the Relic to force your opponent to exile a card from their graveyard, and if the land is the only card in their graveyard, they'll have to exile it (note that the wording of the Relic's first ability allows your opponent to choose which card to exile, so if they have more than one card, you'd have to use the Relic's second ability). This will mean that the land won't be in their graveyard to be returned.

You don't need to do this "in response to the casting", though. Wrenn and Six's "Return up to one target land card from your graveyard to your hand." is a loyalty ability. This goes on the stack, and can also be responded to. So you can wait until Wrenn and Six is on the battlefield, and see whether they use its ability. If they do, you can use the Relic to get rid of the card before the loyalty ability resolves, and this will prevent the card from being returned to your opponent's hand. Generally speaking, it's best to make your opponent commit to an action before responding to it, but there are exceptions.